# Book set on Mars with a hermaphrodite character

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to find the name and author of a SF book I read in the 1970s. It was set on the terraformed Mars of the far future and written in an arty, experimental style. Wealth was unlimited so the characters had everything they needed. The Martians were described as having black hair that was iridescent like all colors of the rainbow. One character was a hermaphrodite named Sysiphos or Sisyphus. She/he had sex with a sibling. When male Sisyphus was referred to as he, when acting as female, she -- as a she she went by the name Sissy. At one point Sissy seduced the teenage son of a politician on Mars and ran into a lot of trouble. I think this book might have serialized in Analog or Fantasy & Science Fiction magazine.

Comment: You've included different details here; https://absolutewrite.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-342334.html

Comment: Never mind -- found it  A Double Shadow, Frederick Turner

Comment: Great, now self-answer it!

Answer (score 2):

Book was [*A Double Shadow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?504), by Frederick Turner, published 1978

[image: Cover of A Double Shadow]

Comment: It would be better to explain *how* this book fits the criteria.

Comment: A quick review could not find anything with a description detailed enough to see if this answer is correct. More info on why it is the answer is needed.

Comment: This is a self-answer from the person who asked the question in the first place. Surely *they* know that this book is correct?

Comment: @F1 self-answered questions are held to the same standards as all others.